# Delta faucet cannot turn off water after shower

Tags: faucet

I have a new installed Delta one handle faucet in my bath.

It worked well. But after just about 2 weeks, it cannot turn off water after shower.

I opened it and it seems spring and seat item are in good situation. I put it back and it worked well.

Unfortunately, it could not turn off again after a related long shower even the handle is turned to close position.

I tested it several time. If I run hot water for a shot time, it can turn off correctly. If I run hot water for a long time, it cannot turn off. I guess somehow the seat item/spring for hot water does not work well.

Should I replace the spring and seat item (it just 2 weeks)? Or, is there a possible install mistake I have made?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is the running water hot or cold? And, how fast is it running?

Comment: The running water is hot. Sometime it runs like lines. Sometime it is pretty fast.